# не импортируются одновременно несколько классов org.apache.http, как импортировать одним разом jar?

Tags: java, http

не могу импортировать одним jar файлом все библиотеки, а в случае загрузки двух jar файлов, создается конфликт, потому что есть общие классы, помогите решить проблему?

```
(в одном jar файле всех классов попросту нет)

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

Comment: Чем собираете проект? Попробуйте использовать, например, maven для разруливания зависимостей и сборки fat-jar.

Comment: уверены что нету общей библиотеки?

Comment: @pavel да, весь интернет обшарил

Comment: @AlexChermenin _fat-jar_?

Comment: @Marks http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Наверное моожно так - `import org.apache.http.*;`

Comment: я так пробовал, не проканало